# NodeJs send Binary Data with Request

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload Image to wordpress using Wordpress rest API.

Everything is working but, proper image is not getting uploaded. However, when i use Curl image is proper.

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media/ \
--header "cache-control: no-cache" \
--header "content-disposition: attachment; filename=hh.jpg" \
--header "authorization: Basic token" \
--header "content-type: image/jpg" \
--data-binary "@C://Users/as/Desktop/App _Ideas/hh.jpg" \
```

This curl request is working properly.

Now, when i converted request to Nodejs

```
request({
        url: ' http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media/',
        headers: {
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
          'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename='+filename,
          'content-type' : 'image/jpg',
          'authorization' : 'Basic token'
        },
        encoding: null,
        method: 'POST',
        body: "@C://Users/as/Desktop/App _Ideas/hh.jpg",
        encoding: null
       }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
               res.json({name : error});
            } else {
              res.json(JSON.parse(response.body.toString()));
            }
       });
```

I'm able to receive json response from wordpress as imge uploaded. But, uploaded image is not proper as binary data passed was not proper.

Wordpress uploades folder shows file `hh.jpg` for size 17 bytes.. On editing with notepad it show `@hh.jpg` which means string data is saved as hh.jpg not the actual binary data.

Any ideas how to pass binary data properly with Nodejs.

Comment: Yeah.... The body you pass is a string. I guess `@path` is curl's syntactic sugar.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis yes you are right. On editing the uploaded image with notepad it show hh.jpg means the string is saved as image due to content-disposition header.

Comment: Any ideas how to upload it correctly ?

Comment: Yeah, try `body: require('fs').createReadStream("C://Users/as/Desktop/App _Ideas/hh.jpg")` ( I am not sure about the correct format of paths in windows, maybe you need backslashes?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it working , We need to create a stream of file using

```
fs.createReadStream(filename);
```

fs module.

```
request({
        url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
          'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + filename,
          'content-type' : 'image/jpg',
          'authorization' : 'Basic token'
        },
        encoding: null,
        body: fs.createReadStream('C://Users/as/Desktop/App _Ideas/hh.jpg')
       }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
               res.json({name : error});
            } else {
              res.json(JSON.parse(response.body.toString()));
            }
       });
```

Comment: Hi. this does not work for me. i should send a tar file (binary data) with a POST http request. I can do it with Postman but now i cannot do it. i code it as you code, with a little deference : `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-tar' }` and  `body: fs.createReadStream(tarFilePath, { encoding: 'binary' })` but it does not send file as postman send. can you give me a little help? or update your answer with axios. because request deprecated.

Comment: can you tell me how to download those files ?

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I almost destroyed my laptop because I couldn't get this working